# Error: Assertion failed: resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name -> Deploying change in Firebase Hosting to Live site

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase-hosting

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "dist/nur",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "nur",
      "public": "dist/nur",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Tried **firebase deploy** command through Firebase to deploy the changes.

```
Deploying to 'nur-beta'...

i  deploying database, storage, firestore, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
database: rules syntax for database nur-beta-default-rtdb is valid
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: reading indexes from firestore.indexes.json...
i  cloud.firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
cloud.firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
```

After all resources deployement it gives assertion failed message.

Error: Assertion failed: resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name. This should have caused an error earlier. May I know what I'm missing while deploying the changes to already LIVE web-site hosted under Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your JSON file.

For deployment to firebase hosting first of all you have to build your project then you push your project to firebase hosting

command to build the project and deploy it to firebase

1. For angular use the ng build command in the terminal of your project location.
2. after building run the firebase deploy command
3. See the Magic

Comment: yes, it worked yogesh. thanks for guiding me with the right steps.

Answer (score 11):

Log out and login in again, at least that's what worked for me

Answer (score 5):

You just have to log in to the console again.

```
firebase login --reauth
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by running
`firebase init` and reinitializing the project.

Answer (score 1):

```
"hosting": [
{
  "source": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "frameworksBackend": {
    "region": "asia-east1"
  }
},
{
  "target": "friendly-travels",
  "source": ".",
  "frameworksBackend": {}
}
],
```

In the first block of the Hosting section, add the entire target line that is in the second block like this

```
"hosting": [
{
  "target": "friendly-travels",
  "source": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "frameworksBackend": {
    "region": "asia-east1"
  }
},
{
  "target": "friendly-travels",
  "source": ".",
  "frameworksBackend": {}
}
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I was logged in with a different user that had no project like this one. Relogin with the correct user could be a solution if you are sure that the project/site exists.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and what worked for me was adding the target name in firebase.json:

```
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "TARGET_NAME",
      ....
    }
  ]
```

Please note that this is a **hotfix**. I have not fully investigated the root cause, but it helped me to deploy the app when I needed it.

Comment: I already specified the target under hosting but for me unfortunetly it didn't work.